# Django save() error

Tags: python, django, python-2.6

I try to save a m2m relation of a model. This ends up in the model you see below. The error I get is:

`save() got multiple values for keyword argument 'force_insert'`

So to me it seems force_insert is passed both in args and kwargs. However when inspecting the values with pdb, I get the following: `args = ()` and `kwargs = {'force_insert': True, 'using': 'default'}`. So force_insert is not present in args. Any ideas why this goes wrong?

```
class TaggedItem(GenericTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
    """
    Also caches team info when available.
    """
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self.content_object, 'team'):
            self.team = self.content_object.team

        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        super(TaggedItem, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tagged Item")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tagged Items")
```

EDIT: As expected, if I delete 'force_insert' from kwargs the save does work.

Stacktrace:

```
D:\Stamkracht\v3\v3_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\backbone\utils.py in _decorated
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\v3_env\lib\site-packages\annoying\decorators.py in wrapper
            output = function(request, *args, **kwargs) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\blog\views.py in create
    return _handle_blog_form(request, blog) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\blog\views.py in _handle_blog_form
            form.save_m2m() # Needed for tags! ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\v3_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in save_m2m
                f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name]) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\taggit\managers.py in save_form_data
        getattr(instance, self.name).set(*value) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\taggit\utils.py in inner
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\taggit\managers.py in set
        self.add(*tags) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\taggit\utils.py in inner
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\taggit\managers.py in add
            self.through.objects.get_or_create(tag=tag, **self._lookup_kwargs()) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\v3_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in get_or_create
        return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\v3_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get_or_create
                obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db) ...

D:\Stamkracht\v3\apps\taggit\models.py in save
        super(TaggedItem, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs) ...
```

Comment: Where exactly is the m2m relation in your code? And can you paste a stacktrace?

Comment: The m2m is quite far away, so to speak. I'll add a stacktrace!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call to `super` is off. You shouldn't be passing `self` into the method. That's already covered by `super`. Use this instead:

```
super(TaggedItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks that was it. I didn't wrote the code for this model, so I kind of assumed it was my error, I should've just compared to other save() methods I wrote.